# graphic card to be used for computationally intense tasks under Linux

Tags: graphics-cards, linux, nvidia

I love Linux. And, I plan on buying a powerful computer for computationally intensive tasks (e.g. machine learning, processing of video and images, etc.). I have seen many on the market, but I can foresee that it will include 32GB (or more) RAM, SSDs, and a GPU card (most likely NVIDIA GeForce series, but I'm open to suggestions).

I am aware that Linux doesn't always have the drivers for some products (especially for NVIDIA), so I am concerned that I might spend a lot of money on hardware and then be unable to use its full capabilities. But at the same time, I would really like to avoid being forced to use Windows.

Thus, I would like to ask you people and experienced users about your success stories (ie., please avoid the "this-is-my-hell-with-NVIDIA-drivers" type of comments). On the contrary, I am interested in hardware combinations that work, considering the following points when possible:

- it has to be under Linux environment only (ie no dual boot)
- it needs to support CUDA
- I am not interested in gaming. But I do want to see nice graphics eg. when editing video.
- I will only use 2-3 'normal' monitors and I am not interested in advanced setups like 4K, HDPI, etc. (Full HD is enough for me)

What other considerations would you advise before buying the computer?

Edit 0: I got a nice overview from [this video](https://youtu.be/9f4B8uIPqcE) but still getting mixed opinions, I would like something a bit more elaborated.

Comment: All Nvidia cards do work under Linux, you just need to install the blob drivers. I would personally reccomend AMD though until I read that you need CUDA. 4090 should work

Comment: NVIDIA gpus with CUDA have always been supported on Linux because that's a huge market for them in data centers. You must use proprietary drivers instead of the open source mesa driver. The desktop environment & gaming experience on NVIDIA GPUs is adequate but due to being closed source and actively preventing open source efforts this generates all of the complaints against NVIDIA. I must say there isn't "driver hell" unless you have a custom kernel and all sorts of non-standard configs that require open source drivers.

Comment: I would also suggest looking into a Coral TPU usb device.  They can augment your processing power.  Other companies probably make similar devices.